# Generar Registros Ordenados De Distintas Tablas

Tags: sql

Tengo un problema que me tiene frustrado desde hace dias, estoy desarrollando una BD en SQL con la estructura de la de la imagen, les explico un poco:

Cada "Parte Terminada" tiene varias "Partes De Blanquins " y a su vez cada "Parte De Blanquin" tiene varias "Partes Estampadas", estas dos ultimas tablas se relacionan con otras tablas como se muestran en la imagen, especialmente con "Troqueles" y "Condición Operación", aunque cada una tiene un valor distinto(una se relaciona con un troquel y la otra con otro distinto).

El problema es que quiero realizar una consulta para mostrar todas las "Partes De Blanquin" y las "Partes estampadas" ambas en una misma columna, tengo una consulta pero solo muestra la una o la otra

Ojala y me puedan ayudar, Gracias...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el codigo de mi consulta:

```
select ltrim (Rtrim(numero_parte)) as 'Parte Terminada', 
nombre_parte as 'Nombre PT', np.numero as 'Parte Estampada',
np.nombre as 'Nombre', modelo as 'Modelo', proveedor as 'Proveedor',  
cliente as 'Cliente', 
np.centro_trabajo as 'Centro De Trabajo', 
np.imagen as 'Imagen', proceso as 'Proceso', 
nombre_proceso as 'Nombre Del Proceso', colchon as 'Colchon', 
linea as 'Linea', prensa as 'Prensa',
np.linea_contin as 'Linea De Contingencia', almacen as 'Almacen',
FROM partes_terminadas pt inner join numero_parte np on   
np.id_partermi=pt.id 
left join partes_estampadas pe on pe.id_bl=np.id 
left join troquel tro on pe.id_troq=tro.id 
left join linea li on tro.id_linea=li.id 
left join condicion_operacion co on pe.id_co=co.id 
left join material mat on np.id_material=mat.id
```

Comment: Podrias generar la base de datos con datos de ejemplo en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) y adjuntar el linck a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

con la información que aportas, deberías reescribir esa consulta sustituyendo este left join:

```
left join partes_estampadas pe on pe.id_bl=np.id
```

Por una supuesta tabla "partes_de_blanquit", cruzándolas por el campo que corresponda.
A su vez, tendrás que reemplazar en la select los campos que vinieran de la tabla anterior por la nueva tabla.
Después, puedes realizar un UNION ALL de ambas consultas, ten en cuenta que han de devolver el mismo número de columnas.
Como ayuda adicional, puedes agregar una columna nueva en cada select que te indique en la salida final de dónde proviene cada resultado.